# Extend power from outdoor frontyard lamp with a modified smart outdoor plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lamp

I have surveillance camera in front of my house that will be plugged in at all times through its USB power adapter. Also, I would occasionally plug in my electric pressure washer and possibly charge my car (yes, it is slow, but enough at 15Amps. AFAIK the car also slows down charging if it detects bad extension cord via voltage drop).

I am considering to get [one of these smart power plugs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JB5TQSG), cut the plug off and attach to the lamp wiring (there was also a ground wire that I forgot to draw):

[image]

**Is this idea fine as I would not be getting a dedicated electrical box that would be installed in the wall? Instead I simply plan to attach this smart power plug to the surface of wall**

Answer (score 1):

It would be a code violation to use a cord for permanent wiring according to the NEC.
It is not UL listed so it is not made for use in the US. Many devices found online have not passed safety evaluation.

Comment: I believe that's in NEC 400.6-400.8.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget this receptacle will also need to be located inside a GFCI protection zone.

Putting the GFCI outdoors is a huge mistake.  The weather will wreck it in short order.   "But it's an outdoor GFCI!" That listing means it is *not unsafe* to use outdoors, it doesn't mean it'll last.  Safety certifications are not durability certifications.  Place the GFCI at an indoor point prior to this outlet, e.g. another receptacle or the breaker itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea. Install a waterproof, outdoor-use electrical box with two outlets, using the existing wiring to feed the new box.

Comment: If it were a listed device and plugged into a receptacle it would be ok but the device is not listed and it is a code violation to use such a device in a permanent wiring method.

Comment: I agree; install an outdoor receptacle with outlets so that you can plug & unplug..